# Formatting Date time to Specific Format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am trying to convert the DateTime to following Format.

```
2015-06-11 07:14:03.930
```

I have tried with ,

```
string plannedStartTime = startTime.ToString("o");
```

> output:2015-06-12T16:54:47.3206929+05:30

and

```
string plannedStartTime = startTime.ToString("u");
```

> output:2015-06-12 16:56:57Z

Not getting any formatters from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Any other Formatters?

Comment: `DateTime.ToString("0")` should throw `FormatException`, doesn't it?

Comment: It's  a "o" , My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) for your output. You need to use [custom date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) specifiers with a culture that have `:` as a [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

```
string plannedStartTime = startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", 
                                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If your `CurrentCulture` already have `:` as a `TimeSeparator`, you don't need to pass second parameter in `ToString` method.

Answer (score 5):

all you need is a right format string

try using this `startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what your asking for

```
string plannedStartTime = startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: You need to use `MM` not `mm` for months. And using `HH` would be better for 24-hour clock time.